# How do we convert jQuery clearQueue().tooltip('dispose') in VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to convert all code from jQuery to pure JavaScript. Currently, I’m doing a part which has to do with jQuery animation and jQuery Tooltips.

Stop time out on the previous tooltip and remove it:

```
$('body>.btn.edit').clearQueue().tooltip('dispose').remove();
```

The above line of code removes the tooltip icon from view upon execution.
[image]

The code segment I cannot seem to understand how to convert to pure JavaScript is this:

```
.clearQueue().tooltip('dispose').remove();
```

Please give me a proper solution to converting this code to pure JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

As in definition it says

> The clearQueue() method removes all items from the queue that have not
>   yet been run. Note that when a function has started to run, it runs
>   until it is completed.

and

> .tooltip('dispose')

Hides and destroys an element’s tooltip.

> .remove();

And Finally removing the element.

Comment: Yes, it does. But in Vanilla how do we dealing with a queue that has not yet been run in animation?